# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas. 
I am trying to assign a negative sign to one of the column in data frame with below code. but while i do that i get error as below.
I tried with below code

```
INTERNAL_DEBIT = InternalTxns[InternalTxns['type'].isin(['INTERNAL_DEBIT','INTERNAL'])]

new_amnt = (INTERNAL_DEBIT['amount']*-1)
```

but i need to assign this negative value to only matching conditions and get entire data. I am looking for simpler and less coding.

I read through other posts for the similar error but most of them are not for similar requirement.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
InternalTxns[[InternalTxns["type"] in ["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER_REVERSAL"]],'amount']=InternalTxns[[InternalTxns["type"] in ["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER_REVERSAL"]],'amount']*-1
```

Comment: IIUC: `InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER_REVERSAL"]),'amount']=InternalTxns['amount']*-1`

Comment: Thanks a ton @EdChum for quick response, but i guess it will result in Syntax error at 'amount']=

Comment: Sorry did you execute this line of code?

Comment: appreciate your help. !, Yep, just now, it does give syntax error.

Comment: how about `InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER‌​_REVERSAL"]),'amount'] *= -1` Also on SO it's common form to post raw data or a link to your data plus your code and desired output rather than images

Comment: still same,  Debug logs :       InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER_REVERSAL"],'amount']= -1
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <function _remove at 0x0000000001F34DD8> ignored

Comment: As I've already stated you need to post raw data and code, otherwise I cant help you further

Comment: Apologies for this @EdChum, but i got the error, i had made a silly mistake of not putting closing bracket. ) for the below code. isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER_‌​REVERSAL"]). Thanks a ton for your help !

Comment: So are you saying that my original snippet: `InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER‌​_REVERSAL"]),'amount']=InternalTxns['amount']*-1` or ` 
how about InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER‌​‌​_REVERSAL"]),'amount'] *= -1` worked or both worked?

Comment: Yep both worked. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the original mask you used from `isin` with `loc` to only overwrite those values:

```
InternalTxns.loc[InternalTxns["type"].isin(["INTERNAL_DEBIT","INTERNAL_TRANSFER‌​‌​_REVERSAL"]),'amount'] *= -1
```